# Symfony - Authentication with an API Token - Request token user is null

Tags: php, symfony, session, authentication

> For the record, I'm using PHP 7.0.0, in a Vagrant Box, with PHPStorm. Oh, and Symfony 3.

I'm following the [API Key Authentication](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/api_key_authentication.html) documentation. My goal is:

- To allow the user to provide a key as a GET `apiKey` parameter to authenticate for *any* route, except the developer profiler etc obviously
- To allow the developer to write `$request->getUser()` in a controller to get the currently logged in user

My problem is that, although I believe I've followed the documentation to the letter, I'm still getting a `null` for `$request->getUser()` in the controller.

*Note: I've removed error checking to keep the code short*

**ApiKeyAuthenticator.php**

> The thing that processes the part of the request to grab the API key from it. It can be a header or anything, but I'm sticking with `apiKey` from GET.

Differences from documentation, pretty much 0 apart from that I'm trying to keep the user authenticated in the session following [this part](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/api_key_authentication.html#storing-authentication-in-the-session) of the docs.

```
class ApiKeyAuthenticator implements SimplePreAuthenticatorInterface
{
    public function createToken(Request $request, $providerKey)
    {
        $apiKey = $request->query->get('apiKey');

        return new PreAuthenticatedToken(
            'anon.',
            $apiKey,
            $providerKey
        );
    }

    public function authenticateToken(TokenInterface $token, UserProviderInterface $userProvider, $providerKey)
    {
        $apiKey = $token->getCredentials();
        $username = $userProvider->getUsernameForApiKey($apiKey);

        // The part where we try and keep the user in the session!
        $user = $token->getUser();
        if ($user instanceof ApiKeyUser) {
            return new PreAuthenticatedToken(
                $user,
                $apiKey,
                $providerKey,
                $user->getRoles()
            );
        }


        $user = $userProvider->loadUserByUsername($username);

        return new PreAuthenticatedToken(
            $user,
            $apiKey,
            $providerKey,
            $user->getRoles()
        );
    }

    public function supportsToken(TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        return $token instanceof PreAuthenticatedToken && $token->getProviderKey() === $providerKey;
    }
}
```

**ApiKeyUserProvider.php**

> The custom user provider to load a user object from wherever it can be loaded from - I'm sticking with the default DB implementation.

Differences: only the fact that I have to inject the repository into the constructor to make calls to the DB, as the docs allude to but don't show, and also returning `$user` in `refreshUser()`.

```
class ApiKeyUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    protected $repo;

    // I'm injecting the Repo here (docs don't help with this)
    public function __construct(UserRepository $repo)
    {
        $this->repo = $repo;
    }

    public function getUsernameForApiKey($apiKey)
    {
        $data = $this->repo->findUsernameByApiKey($apiKey);

        $username = (!is_null($data)) ? $data->getUsername() : null;

        return $username;
    }

    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        return $this->repo->findOneBy(['username' => $username]);
    }

    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
    {
        // docs state to return here if we don't want stateless
        return $user;
    }

    public function supportsClass($class)
    {
        return 'Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User' === $class;
    }
}
```

**ApiKeyUser.php**

> This is my custom user object.

The only difference I have here is that it contains doctrine annotations (removed for your sanity) and a custom field for the token. Also, I removed `\Serializable` as it didn't seem to be doing anything and apparently Symfony only needs the `$id` value to recreate the user which it can do itself.

```
class ApiKeyUser implements UserInterface
{
    private $id;
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $email;
    private $salt;
    private $apiKey;
    private $isActive;

    public function __construct($username, $password, $salt, $apiKey, $isActive = true)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->salt = $salt;
        $this->apiKey = $apiKey;
        $this->isActive = $isActive;
    }

    //-- SNIP getters --//
}
```

**security.yml**

```
# Here is my custom user provider class from above
providers:
    api_key_user_provider:
        id: api_key_user_provider

firewalls:
    # Authentication disabled for dev (default settings)
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    # My new settings, with stateless set to false
    secured_area:
        pattern: ^/
        stateless: false
        simple_preauth:
            authenticator: apikey_authenticator
        provider:
            api_key_user_provider
```

**services.yml**

Obviously I need to be able to inject the repository into the provider.

```
api_key_user_repository:
    class: Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
    factory: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", getRepository]
    arguments: [AppBundle\Security\ApiKeyUser]

api_key_user_provider:
    class:  AppBundle\Security\ApiKeyUserProvider
    factory_service: doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager
    factory_method: getRepository
    arguments: ["@api_key_user_repository"]

apikey_authenticator:
    class: AppBundle\Security\ApiKeyAuthenticator
    public: false
```

Debugging. It's interesting to note that, in `ApiKeyAuthenticator.php`, the call to `$user = $token->getUser();` in `authenticateToken()` always shows an `anon.` user, so it's clearly not being stored in the session.

[image: Debug 1]
[image: Debug 2]

Also note how at the bottom of the authenticator we do actually return a new `PreAuthenticatedToken` with a user found from the database:

[image: Debug 3]
[image: Debug 4]

So it's clearly found me and is returning what it's supposed to here, but the user call in the controller returns `null`. What am I doing wrong? Is it a failure to serialise into the session because of my custom user or something? I tried setting all the user properties to public as somewhere in the documentation suggested but that made no difference.

Comment: Can you try to test this, add to your firewall:     `access_control:
        - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }`

Comment: I added this as a key under `security` in `security.yml`. No change.

Comment: Could you try by setting all your properties in the ApiKeyUser class as protected?

Comment: @hasumedic I've tried both `public` and `protected` access modifiers and the user was still `null`.

Comment: Uhm, then can you try changing your implementation of ApiKeyUserProvider::supportsClass for 'return ApiKeyUser::class === $class;'?

Comment: @hasumedic I've made that change, it's still `null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turns out that calling `$request->getUser()` in the controller *doesn't actually return the currently authenticated user* as I would have expected it to. This would make the most sense for this object API imho.

If you actually look at the code for `Request::getUser()`, it looks like this:

```
/**
 * Returns the user.
 *
 * @return string|null
 */
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->headers->get('PHP_AUTH_USER');
}
```

That's for HTTP Basic Auth! In order to get the currently logged in user, you need to do this every single time:

```
$this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
```

This does, indeed, give me the currently logged in user. Hopefully the question above shows how to authenticate successfully by API token anyway.

Alternatively, don't call `$this->get()` as it's a service locator. Decouple yourself from the controller and inject the token service instead to get the token and user from it.

Answer (score 1):

To get the currently logged in User inside your Controller simply call:

```
$this->getUser();
```

This will refer to a method in Symfony's ControllerTrait, which basically wraps the code provided in Jimbo's answer.

```
protected function getUser()
{
    if (!$this->container->has('security.token_storage')) {
        throw new \LogicException('The SecurityBundle is not registered in your application. Try running "composer require symfony/security-bundle".');
    }

    if (null === $token = $this->container->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()) {
        return;
    }

    if (!is_object($user = $token->getUser())) {
        // e.g. anonymous authentication
        return;
    }

    return $user;
}
```

Comment: Although this is helpful for some (and thanks for your answer Marco!), there are a few things that need to be mentioned. `$this->container` is a service locator (anti-pattern) and we should use Dependency Injection instead. Also, traits in general and coupling to Symfony by extending Symfony's controller class are also considered poor practices by many (coupling). Hope that helps!